# How can I get a comment that corresponds to a post in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm going to make an API that only brings up comments from the post when I send a request to the router with comments attached to the pk value of the post. So urls as follows. After writing py and views.py, I sent the request and 404 error occurred. How can I get comments by composing an API? Here's the code I made.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post', CreateReadPostView.as_view({'post': 'create', 'get': 'list'})),
    path('post/<int:pk>', UpdateDeletePostView.as_view({'put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update', 'delete': 'destroy'})),
    path('post/<int:post.pk>/comments', CreateReadCommentView.as_view({'post': 'create', 'get': 'list'})),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
class CreateReadCommentView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()

    def perform_create (self, serializer) :
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: you can check [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)

Comment: since you have the url structure already, you can just use override `get_queryset()` method and not use the `drf-nested-routers` library. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `get_queryset()` method.

**models.py**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('post/<int:post_id>/comments', CreateReadCommentView.as_view({'post': 'create', 'get': 'list'})),
]
```

**views.py**

```py
class CreateReadCommentView (ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(post=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
```